# Can it be that the infinitude of primes in sequence $n^2+1$ implies infinitude of primes in similar sequences (with the help of some conjectures)?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

> Are there some conjectures that imply that the sequence $n^2+1$ takes an infinite number of prime values if and only if every sequence of the form $n^2+k$ (where $k \in \mathbb N$) takes an infinite number of prime values?

Answer (score 2):

By the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), $n^2+k$ has infinitely many prime values if $f(x)=x^2+k$ is irreducible over the integers, and the values $f(n)$ are relatively prime. This would apply for all positive $k$.

Comment: But does that conjecture gives us a way to deduce that if $n^2 + 1$ has an infinite number of prime values then every sequence of the form $n^2 + k$ where $k$ is natural number has an infinite number of prime values? That conjecture only asserts, in its less general form, that $n^2 + k$ will have an infinite number of prime values, but my question is somehow different.

Comment: By the conjecture you also obtain that the claim is true for $n^2+1$ iff it is true for $n^2+k$ - just because it is always true.

Comment: But it still does not give a way of how to deduce that the case $n^2+1$ implies cases $n^2+k$. It "only" gives solution to all cases without giving a clue how to deduce all cases from just one single case.

Comment: I am not convinced that it is reasonable to expect that the case $n^2+1$ implies all cases $n^2+k$ - except for the trivial reason, that they are all true.

Comment: If it looks hard it does not mean that it is not reasonable.

Comment: For me it is not reasonable, because I believe, that the proof will go differently. Already for the linear problem - Dirichlet's theorem for infinitely many primes in $ax+b$, it did not really work that way - that the case $b=1$ implies the other cases. However, I think, this is a discussion for "meta".

Comment: But you know that there are sometimes different ways to prove some theorem.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yeah – but do you have the slightest reason for thinking that there is some conjecture which, when added to $n^2+1$ being prime infinitely often, will lead to $n^2+k$ being prime infinitely often for all $k\ge1$? You know, anyone can stick two well-known unsolved problems together, and ask whether there's a third unsolved problem that will draw an arrow between the two, but such ungrounded speculation is not how we make progress in Mathematics.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, but I thought that even a question that is just an idea was worth posting, if only because it can lead us to fruitful thinking.